# How to plot a histogram of this type using matplotlib from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i am thinking to plot a histogram on raining vs non raining in terms of hours.
[I have a following dataframe listing of hour from 0 to 23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVbt9.png)

[i tried plotting but i am not able to understand from it that how many were raining in that hour and how many were not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr8nY.png)

```
Hour    Raining     Not Raining

0   0   3559751.0   7248389.0

1   1   1606880.0   3361780.0


2   2   145719.0    282413.0


3   3   26804.0     54543.0


4   4   766333.0    1672134.0


5   5   379272.0    800500.0


6   6   59030.0     123764.0


7   7   140758.0    242930.0

8   8   1950224.0   3544500.0

9   9   3806660.0   7234291.0

10  10  477959.0    837528.0

11  11  235289.0    410994.0

12  12  7787028.0   15026342.0


13  13  3145361.0   6265131.0

14  14  388437.0    776277.0

15  15  149688.0    297624.0

16  16  5735102.0   11601840.0

17  17  4250723.0   8442271.0

18  18  564774.0    1123973.0

19  19  290350.0    544482.0

20  20  8302496.0   16203000.0

21  21  4452747.0   8668253.0

22  22  418217.0    784093.0

23  23  115005.0    230668.0
```

now i want to plot a histogram such that i should have a clear understanding that in these hours 1 to 2 how many values were raining and how many were not?

these are hours and bin size should be hour right?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, instead of creating new answers to discuss you issue, add your new details by editing your question (1st post) or in its comments (where this comment is).

Comment: Regarding your question, put your data directly into the question as plain text or in a file, but not an image. And, more importantly, be more detailed in your question (e.g. What requirements do you have for plotting your histogram? Size of bins, etc.)

Comment: You should be submitting your question when it is in a state where it can be answered not when it's a "work in progress".

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: Can you share what you plotted and what's confusing about it?

Comment: its above in the link see above

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is a stacked column chart.

The below code will produce this for you.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 3559751.0, 7248389.0],[1, 1606880.0, 3361780.0],[2, 145719.0, 282413.0],[3,26804.0, 54543.0],[4,766333.0 ,1672134.0],[5,379272.0 ,800500.0],[6,59030.0, 123764.0],[7,140758.0, 242930.0],[8,1950224.0, 3544500.0],[9,3806660.0, 7234291.0],[10,477959.0, 837528.0],[11,235289.0 ,410994.0],[12,7787028.0, 15026342.0],[13, 3145361.0, 6265131.0],[14, 388437.0, 776277.0],[15, 149688.0, 297624.0],[16, 5735102.0 ,11601840.0],[17,4250723.0, 8442271.0],[18,564774.0, 1123973.0],[19,290350.0, 544482.0],[20,8302496.0, 16203000.0],[21,4452747.0, 8668253.0],[22,418217.0, 784093.0],[23, 115005.0, 230668.0]], columns=["hour", "T", "F"])

df[['T', 'F']].plot(kind='bar', stacked='True')
```

I hope this helps!

---

Is this more like what you're after?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 3559751.0, 7248389.0],[1, 1606880.0, 3361780.0],[2, 145719.0, 282413.0],[3,26804.0, 54543.0],[4,766333.0 ,1672134.0],[5,379272.0 ,800500.0],[6,59030.0, 123764.0],[7,140758.0, 242930.0],[8,1950224.0, 3544500.0],[9,3806660.0, 7234291.0],[10,477959.0, 837528.0],[11,235289.0 ,410994.0],[12,7787028.0, 15026342.0],[13, 3145361.0, 6265131.0],[14, 388437.0, 776277.0],[15, 149688.0, 297624.0],[16, 5735102.0 ,11601840.0],[17,4250723.0, 8442271.0],[18,564774.0, 1123973.0],[19,290350.0, 544482.0],[20,8302496.0, 16203000.0],[21,4452747.0, 8668253.0],[22,418217.0, 784093.0],[23, 115005.0, 230668.0]], columns=["hour", "T", "F"])

ax = df.plot(x="hour", y="T", kind="bar", color="blue", alpha=0.3)
df.plot(x="hour", y="F", kind="bar", ax=ax, color="green", alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

Comment: i did that stuff but i want the same what you did in form of histograms, that is able to understood. thanks

Comment: i want the same in form of histograms on x axis all hours and on y axis values of that in range. i tried but i am not able to understand from that figure

Comment: If we could limit the x-axis to hours, our frequency would always be 2?

Comment: You are using kind='bar' that's inappropriate i want that stuff with a histogram kind='hist' but the graph isnt understandable.

Comment: When using a histogram one of the two axes are going to be the frequency. If we were to use time as the X axes we would force distribution to be on the y, which we already know to be 1 per column.

Comment: Yup that's the issue.

Comment: Then why are you wanting to use a histogram?